# MutationObserver create infinite loop when I replace a string with <span> tag

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, contenteditable, mutation-observers

I would like to replace all occurence with a html contenteditable div. I need to replace the occurence with a  tag to customize this with a css.
But when I try to replace with a span, MutationObserver generate a infinite loop...

```
document.designMode = "on";

var text = document.getElementById('text');

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations =>
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    console.log(text.textContent);
    // let a = "a";
    // a.style.color = "red";
    text.textContent = text.textContent.replace('/', '<span>/</span>');
    observer.disconnect(); 
    const range = document.createRange();
    const textNode = text.firstChild;
    range.setStart(textNode, text.textContent.length);
    range.setEnd(textNode, text.textContent.length);
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    // observer.disconnect(); 
  })
);

observer.observe(text, {
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true,
  
});
```

```
<p id="text" contenteditable="true">I'm a text will be change</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The infinite loop is caused by replacing typed `/` characters with `<span>/</span>` without turning off the observer first - each replacement triggers the observer again.

The solution for this problem is simple: turn the observer off before replacement and turn it on again afterwards:

```js
"use strict";
document.designMode = "on";

var text = document.getElementById('text');

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations =>
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    console.log(text.textContent);
    observer.disconnect(); // turn observer off;
    text.textContent = text.textContent.replace('/', '<span>/</span>');

    const range = document.createRange();
    const textNode = text.firstChild;
    range.setStart(textNode, text.textContent.length);
    range.setEnd(textNode, text.textContent.length);
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    observe(); // turn back on 
  })
);

const observe = ()=> {

  observer.observe(text, {
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true,
   
  });
};
observe();
```

```css
span { background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<p id="text" contenteditable="true">I'm a text will be change</p>
```

But this only hightlights a potential new problem: the code replaces `textContent` with HTML which, because it's inside a text node, is displayed in source form, and because `<span>/</span>` is inside a text node, CSS to highlight SPAN elements in yellow doesn't work (it's not a SPAN element).

Assuming the span element should be rendered as HTML, the design problem now becomes how to replace newly typed forward slashes with a SPAN element in the DOM, not in a text node. The [`mutation.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) property of Mutation Records may be a good place to start by splitting it into three nodes: a textnode for text before the `/`, an element node for `<span>/</span>` and a final textnode for text following the `/` if any, followed by repositioning the cursor after the span node if required.

Comment: 1. The `observer.disconnect()` and `observe()` calls should be outside the mutation loop, otherwise you're just toggling it off and on many times for no reason.

2. I've found that simply calling `observer.takeRecords()` at the end of the callback works even better.

Comment: I absolutely agree that placing `disconnect` and `observe` calls outside the loop would be technically superior. Testing if one would ever get multiple mutations in a callback from observing `text` is not something I looked into and apriorially considered unlikely.